# include_once in PHPUnit does not include functions

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit

So I'm using `PHPUnit` within my WordPress installation to test custom functions I've written for a plugin.

I'm able to use classes that I write effectively through the test classes I'm writing, however when I try to use `include_once` or `require_once` within the test file to bring in some functions that are not methods on a class, the test file doesn't recognize the function.

For example, here is and example test class I've written:
**test-engage.php**

```
function engage() {
    return "Engage";
}
```

And here is the file with the function I've tried to import:
**engage.php**

```
class Test_Enagage extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function test_engage() {
        $test_url = getcwd() . "/engage.php";
        include_once($test_url);
        echo engage();
    }
}
```

I've also tried importing the **engage.php** file at the top of the file before the class is declared like below:
**test-engage.php**

```
$test_url = getcwd() . "/engage.php";
        include_once($test_url);
class Test_Enagage extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function test_engage() {

        echo engage();
    }
}
```

But either way I get the error within my console when I run `phpunit`:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Test_Enagage::test_engage Error: Call to undefined function
>   engage()

So it's not recognizing that this function even exists.

Again, I can create a test class within that file that has a method of engage like so:

```
class Engage {
public function engage() {
    echo "Engage";
}
}
```

and the test file calls class and method no problem and the tests pass.

Here is my folder structure:

```
plugins
-myplugin
--engage.php
--tests
---test-engage.php
```

and the function `getcwd()` returns the path to `myplugin` (verfied by simple `echo` statement at the top of the `test-engage.php` file)

Does anyone have any advice on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Does it blow up if you `require_once` instead of `include_once`?

Comment: No it just does the same thing.